# Redirect Page without changing the URL in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, regex

in ASP.NET if we use `Server.Transfer(WebForm1.aspx)`
This actually sent the request to the new page and in browser the new page has been loaded but the URL remains same. is there any way to do the same in PHP?

Just asking if it is possible or not. And if it is possible then how?

Comment: I do believe the best you can do is to simple "include" the file you want into the PHP page called. Otherwise, this action would be best done within a .htaccess

Comment: if I do a include statement, will it actually loads up the new page content on the browser?
Anyways thanks for the reply and not putting a -1 to the question :)

Comment: An include will simply insert the included page's "stuff" into the page you have the include in.

Comment: @iSaumya: I believe the "include" idea would be to have a content-less page which performs the conditional check (which page to "include") and then includes the intended content page based on that condition.  Something like: "if (some condition) { include file 1 } else { include file 2 }"  The actual HTML content would be in file 1 and file 2.

Comment: @David: thanks for the reply. If I do include in a if else condition, you sure it will load up the complete new page? I've used include only for including some function and business condition stuffs, but never thought of it will actually redirect the whole page in behind and loads up the complete new page.

Comment: @iSaumya: It will include whatever is being included.  The PHP engine has no notion of a "whole page" or anything conceptual about the resulting UI.  If you include a file, that file will essentially be placed in its entirety in that location when the code is processing it.

Comment: Then its better to add the html tag, then the rest part on every php file then include them as per need. Thanks great info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require('/WebForm1.aspx");
```

I think PHP doesn't have a 'transfer' function, but you could get the exact same behaviour using include() or require()